# select menu showing undefined not a generated word from array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Basically I have an app that you guess what the english word for the french word is! For some reason my select menu is showing undefined and not a english word? I can't figure out why!!

#### Here is my jsFiddle, A exact replica of the application. The first time you run it, undefined won't show but on the second iteration it shows 2 undefined options??

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesw1/w8p7b6p3/16/

#### Javascript:

```
    //James Wainwright's Mobile Apps Assignment
    //Arrays of french and english words.
    var
    RanNumbers = new Array(6),
        foreignWords = ['un', 'deux', 'trois', 'quatre', 'cinq', 'six', 'sept', 'huit', 'neuf', 'dix', 'onze', 'douze', 'treize', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'seize', 'dix-sept', 'dix-huit', 'dix-neuf', 'vingt', 'vingt et un', 'vingt-deux', 'vingt-trois', 'vingt-quatre', 'vingt-cinq', 'vingt-six', 'vingt-sept', 'vingt-huit', 'vingt-neuf', 'trente'],
        translate = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty', 'twenty-one', 'twenty-two', 'twenty-three', 'twenty-four', 'twenty-five', 'twenty-six', 'twenty-seven', 'twenty-eight', 'twenty-nine', 'thirty'],
        number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30)),
        output = '',
        correctAns = translate[number];

    //Generate random numbers and make sure they aren't the same as each other.
    function wordGen() {
    for (var h = 0; h < RanNumbers.length; h++) {
        var temp = 0;
        do {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            while(temp==correctAns){
              temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            }
        } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
        RanNumbers[h] = temp;

    }
} 

        //Call the previous function
        wordGen();

    //Create dynamic select menu using for loop. This loop runs once (on document load)
    document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent = foreignWords[number];
    var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < RanNumbers.length; i++) {
            guess += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";
    }
    guess += '<option value="6">' + correctAns + '</option>';
    guess += "</select>";

    //Output the previous.
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = guess;
    numGuessed = document.getElementById('guesses').value;

    function arrayValueIndex(arr, val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] === val) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Declare variables 'outside' the onclick function so it ensures they work correctly.
    var numGames = 5;
    var numGuesses = 1;
    var correct = 0;
    var wrong = 0;
    var prevNumber;
    var counter = 0;
    var outputted = '';

    //Create arrays that will hold the options they chose, the correct answer for that particular question, and ofcourse the generated word.
    var guessedList = new Array(6);
    var correctList = new Array(6);
    var wordGenerated = new Array(6);

    //On click, Get new word, Calculate how many they got right/wrong, Show the user what they entered, show them the correct values they should've guessed and more...
    document.getElementById('submitAns').onclick = function () {

    //Declare variables for function.
        prevNumber = number;
        number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30)),
        output = '',
        correctAns = translate[number];
        document.getElementById('numGuess').innerHTML = "Question #" + numGuesses;

    //Check if guess is right or wrong, if right add 1 to correct pile..Visa versa.
         var
        genWord = document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent,
            select = document.getElementById('guesses'),
            selectedText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        prevNumber === arrayValueIndex(translate, selectedText) ? correct++ : wrong++;

        //Getting new random numbers that aren't duplicates.
        /*function wordGen() {
            for (var j = 0; j < RanNumbers.length; j++) {
                var temp = 0;
                do {
                    temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
                } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
                RanNumbers[j] = temp;

            }
        }*/

        //Generate a word here. ( call wordGen() ) 
        wordGen();

        //Create dynamic select menu for options they have to choose from.
        document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent = foreignWords[number];

        //Generate a random number, so that the 'Correct' answer can be randomly put in a position in the select menu. (It won't always be in the same position...It changes depending on the random number
        var correctAnswerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

        //If it's 0...Change it.
        if(correctAnswerIndex == 0)
        {
            correctAnswerIndex++;   
        }

        //Create a select menu of the options...Add the correct answer randomly into the menu.
        var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
        for (var i = 1; i < RanNumbers.length; i++) {
            //This randomizes where the correct answer will be.
            if(i == correctAnswerIndex)
                 guess += '<option value="'+i+'">' + correctAns + '</option>';
            else
                 guess += "<option selected='selected' value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";

        }
        guess += "</select>";

        //Outputting to the html page.
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = guess;
        numGuessed = document.getElementById('guesses').value;

        function arrayValueIndex(arr, val) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] === val) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        //Checking of the answers below, Accumilating correct and wrong answer. 
        //Count number of guesses
        numGuesses++;
        //Counter for placing guessed, correct and foreign word into there arrays.
        counter++;

        wordGenerated[counter] = foreignWords[number];
        guessedList[counter] = document.getElementById('guesses').options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        correctList[counter] = translate[number];

       //Once the application has finished...It will produce the following output.
        if (numGuesses == 6) {
            document.getElementById('generatedWord').innerHTML = "<span style='font-size:12px;color:red';>Please click for a new game when ready!</span><br /><p>You got " + wrong + " questions wrong " + "<br />You got " + correct + " questions correct";
                $('#submitAns').hide();
                outputted = "<table>";
                for(var d=1;d<wordGenerated.length;d++){
                    outputted += "<tr><td>Question " + d + ":</td> <td>Generated word: " + wordGenerated[d] + "</td>    <td>Guessed Word: " + guessedList[d] + "</td>   <td>Correct Word: " + correctList[d] + "</td></td>";
                }
                outputted += "</table>";

                //Output it to the html page.
                    document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = outputted;
        }
    };
```

#### Html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>James' Translation Guessing Game</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="main">  
        <h2 id="display" style="color:rgba(204,51,204,1);">Guess what the generated french word translates to in English!</h2><br />

        <!-- What question we're upto -->
        <h2 id="numGuess">Question #</h2 >

        <!-- The generated French Word  Aswell as end of app details-->
        <div align="center" class="frenchWord" style="position:">

        <!--Generated french word details-->
             <div style="background-color:rgba(51,51,51,0.5);border-radius:4px 10px 2px;"align="center"  id="generatedWord"></div>
             <br />
             <br />
   <!-- Show the user there guessed answers, correct and foreign word -->
             <div id="details"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Select menu output -->
        <div align="center" id="output"></div>

        <!-- Buttons, Call Functions -->
        <button type="button" style='opacity:0.5' id="submitAns" onClick="translate();">Check</button>
        <input type="button" value="New Game" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
             <script>
             //Simple animation
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#generatedWord").animate({
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    margin: "40px 0px 100px 0px",
                    width: "20%",
                    padding: "30px",
                }, 1500 );
});
</script>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>James Wainwright</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop used to check the correct answer accesses your random number array. This should be less than 6, instead of less than or equal to 6, due to the size of the array (size of 6, accessed with 0-5) Change the code as follows

current code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
```

correction: (decrease the index and change <= to < )

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
```

Also, you add your answer in after generating the list of values initially. You should check to ensure that the correct value is not already in the list. Sometimes it appears twice.

You could add a conditional in your random number generation, that ensures it does not select the correct value.

```
function wordGen() {
    for (var h = 0; h < RanNumbers.length; h++) {
        var temp = 0;
        do {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            while(temp==correctAns){
              temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            }
        } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
        RanNumbers[h] = temp;

    }
}
```

EDIT: Upon further inspection, I noticed that your initial list generation creates a dropdown with 7 options (value 0-5, and value of 6 for correct answer added). Then within your onclick function, you use the indices 1-6 for your for loop, effectively creating 6 answers. I would recommend reducing the indices of your first for loop to 0-4 and adding your answer as the 6th option (with value 5), and then modifying your for loop as above.

Comment: See my added code. It will set temp once, and then continue to set temp equal to a new random value if the temp value was equal to the correct value

Comment: Also, you do not have to declare the wordGen function twice, you should only declare it the first time. In fact, the second declaration (inside the onclick function) will overwrite the first, so either make my above correction in both places, or remove the second declaration. I recommend removing the second declaration. happy coding! :]

Comment: Should I change my current wordGen() with the updated one you commented? You mean the wordGen() outside the .onClick function right?

Comment: Thanks! this helped me so much!!! ^ my last comment was before I saw your second comment.

Comment: By removing the second declaration of wordGen(){ code.. } will i have to just add wordGen(); instead of all the code?

Comment: I just realised that now my app will generate duplicate french words? I've added my updated code to the question

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at this. Do you think you could make it a new question and add a link here in the comments? Also, can you update the JSfiddle on the new question page with the most current code? Once you do I will take a look. 

And as per your previous question, yes you only have to declare the function once and then you can call it anywhere. Just make sure it is not declared inside a function (such as onclick) because then you will not be able to use it outside the scope of that function

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem might be in this for loop:

The array is declared with a length of 6, so you have indexes 0-5 available.  When i = 6, you'll be accessing an index that is out of bounds.  Changing the termination condition to i<6 appears to fix the issue from some quick testing.

You might also need to set i=0, unless you specifically need to access the 2nd index (i=1).

```
//Create a select menu of the options...Add the correct answer randomly into the menu.
    var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        //This randomizes where the correct answer will be.
        if(i == correctAnswerIndex)
             guess += '<option value="'+i+'">' + correctAns + '</option>';
        else
             guess += "<option selected='selected' value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";

    }
```